# Android Navigation drawer fragments

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am working on an Android application that implements a NavigationDrawer.

The NavigationDrawer works fine, so do the fragments transitions but I can't access the Fragment's elements.

Here there is my drawer `onItemClick()` listener's code:

```
ConfigureFragment configure = new ConfigureFragment();
Button bt;
InFragment in = new InFragment();
OutFragment out = new OutFragment();
ConditioningFragment cond = new ConditioningFragment();
private String lft = null;
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    selectItem(position);
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            if(lft == null){
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent,configure,"ConfigureFragment");
            transaction.commit();
            lft = "ConfigureFragment";
            }else{
                transaction.replace(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(lft).getId(),configure,"ConfigureFragment");
                transaction.commit();
                lft = "ConfigureFragment";
            }
        bt = (Button)configure.getView().findViewById(R.id.configure_bt); //throws NullPointerException
        break;
        case 1:
            if(lft == null){
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent,in,"InFragment");
                transaction.commit();
                lft = "InFragment";
            }else{
                transaction.replace(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(lft).getId(),in,"InFragment");
                transaction.commit();
                lft = "InFragment";
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(lft == null){
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent,out,"OutFragment");
                transaction.commit();
                lft = "OutFragment";
            }else{
                transaction.replace(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(lft).getId(),out,"OutFragment");
                transaction.commit();
                lft = "OutFragment";
            }
            break;
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`String` variables don't work with operators like, `==`. You need to use:

```
stringVariableOne.equals(stringVariableTwo);
```

In order to check if the value of one `String` variable(`stringVariableOne`, in this case) is equal to another `String` variable or `null`(`stringVariableTwo`, in this case).

Example:

```
lft.equals(null);
```

Comment: What? If the string is null the object is null, and how can you call an object method if the object is null? His comparing lft == null or lft != null is the correct way.

Comment: That's a misconception. Upon setting an object's value to `null`, the object itself **DOES NOT** become `null`. In this case, if the value of a `String` object is set `null` doesn't make the object `null` from `String `. It just sets the **value** of the `String` object to `null`. I know this well because I've suffered a lot due to all these misconceptions. :-)

Comment: Ok I know that, but it isn't my problem. When I use fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.thefragmentitem) I get a NullPointerException. Why?

Comment: But... I can't find that line in your question. Can you post the whole code?

Comment: @Lorenzo I believe you're getting a `NullPointerException` because, in your `else` block, you're using the method `getId()` on a raw fragment which will not return it's container view's Id if it has an Id assigned to itself. So, basically you're passing the fragment's id to the method `replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)` whereas you're supposed to give your container view's Id. The correct method to get the container view's Id is, `((ViewGroup) fragment.getView().getParent().getId();`. Hope this helps.